# Android Media Recorder - Stream and store video

Tags: android, streaming, mediarecorder

I am required to simultaneously stream, and store video on an SD card (stored on the device we are streaming from) using Android media recorder. I know how to achieve one, or the other.

Is it possible to achieve this? Perhaps there is a way to set multiple output files?

Edit: I've come across a few similar questions which I hadn't found originally. However, these don't seem to have any definitive answers...